# Information about the cyclic group $C_{p^n}$, where $p$ is prime and $n\geq 2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, galois-theory

My question is quite generic and I need it to have an idea of the knowledge of this group. In particular, I am interested in the extension of number fields whose Galois group is $C_{p^n}$ (if there is a general prototype, intermidiate extension, etc..).

I'm looking for more informations as possible, as well as for precise reference (and not only wikipedia or some basics Algebra books).

Thank you very much!

Cheers.

Comment: If the Galois group of $K$ over $F$ is the cyclic group of order $p^n$, then the intermediate extensions correspond to the subgroups of that cyclic group.

Comment: Is it true also for non cyclic Galois group? I mean, the Galois Correspondence Theorem states that for general groups, doesn't it?

Comment: Or maybe do you mean that is the Galois group is cyclic, then the extension is Galois?

Comment: Asking what relative number field extensions have Galois group $C(p^n)$ is not asking "about" $C(p^n)$. All abelian extensions of number fields exist within cyclotomic extensions (Kronecker-Weber theorem).

Comment: The way I use the term "Galois group", Guest_13, it's only defined for extensions that are normal and seperable, that is, Galois extensions. And with that definition, you are of course correct that, whatever the Galois group, the Galois Correspondence Theorem states that the intermediate extensions correspond to the subgroups. From the wording of your question, it wasn't clear what you knew and what you didn't know.

Answer (score 2):

Did you know that every $C_{p^n}$-extension of $\Bbb Q$ is contained in a cyclotomic extension $\Bbb Q(\zeta)$, $\zeta$ being a suitable root of unity? It’s also possible to describe the cyclic extensions of quadratic imaginary fields, and beyond that it’s not an easy story. You might start by finding out about Kronecker’s *Jugendtraum*.

Comment: No, I didn't know both of them, so thank you!

Comment: I suppose I should have said as well that every extension of finite fields is cyclic, so that you can get the particular cyclic Galois groups you were wondering about from such extensions. And that the general question of which abelian Galois groups occur for extensions of general number fields is covered by Class Field Theory. And that there isa Local Class Field Theory describing the abelian extensions of local fields like the $p$-adic numbers and their finite extensions.